# How to pass a deleter to a method in the same class that is held by a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, shared-ptr, raii

I have several classes from 3rd party library similar to the class, StagingConfigDatabase, which requires to be destroyed after it is created. I am using a shared_ptr for RAII but would prefer to create the shared_ptr using a **single line of code** rather than using a seperate template functor as my example shows. Perhaps using lambdas?  or bind?

```
struct StagingConfigDatabase
{
  static StagingConfigDatabase* create();
  void destroy();
};

template<class T>
    struct RfaDestroyer
    {
        void operator()(T* t)
        {
            if(t) t->destroy();
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
      shared_ptr<StagingConfigDatabase> pSDB(StagingConfigDatabase::create(), RfaDestroyer<StagingConfigDatabase>());
    return 1;
    }
```

I was considering something like:

```
shared_ptr<StagingConfigDatabase> pSDB(StagingConfigDatabase::create(), [](StagingConfigDatabase* sdb) { sdb->destroy(); } );
```

but that doesn't compile :(

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume that `create` is static in `StagingConfigDatabase` because your initial code wouldn't compile without it. Regarding destruction, you can use a simple [`std::mem_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/) :

```
#include <memory>

boost::shared_ptr<StagingConfigDatabase> pSDB(StagingConfigDatabase::create(), std::mem_fun(&StagingConfigDatabase::destroy));
```

Answer (score 3):

What compiler are you using? Does it support C++0x features like lambdas? The following (which is basically the same as your example) compiles and works fine for me under MSVC 2010:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct X
{
    static X *create()
    {
        std::cout << "X::create\n";
        return new X;
    }

    void destroy()
    {
        std::cout << "X::destroy\n";
        delete this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto p = std::shared_ptr<X>(X::create(), [](X *p) { p->destroy(); });
    return 0;
}
```

By "works fine", I mean "outputs X::create followed by X::destroy".

Comment: +1  @Stuart Thanks for your help. I'm using MSVC 2010.  mem_fun looks neater so I will choose that as answer.

Comment: @T33C: Fair dos, I agree it's probably better in this instance.

Comment: @T33C: Actually I find lambdas neater (much more explicit), but I would not discard `mem_fun` because C++0x compilers are not quite there yet... hell we don't have a standard yet :p